# Wordpress woocommerce empty my account + car page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am stuck when trying to install woocommerce. I add managed to do it, but suddenly, I don't know why, the "my account" page and "cart" page are empty, if I look into the source code, the content is here but between  and therefore invisible. I have no idea and have been searching for hours on internet and stackoverflow with no luck!
Has anyone an idea of why this is doing this?

I have re-installed three times the plug-in, deleted everything and reinstalled it, it sill does the same error....

[image]

I haven't touched anything in the code and the pages are chosen in the backend

[image]

EDIT :
My woocommercePage is

```
<?php get_header(); ?> 
<?php woocommerce_content(); ?> 
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And my page is :

```
   <?php get_header(); ?> 
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
<?php endwhile; ?> 
<?php else : ?>
 <?php endif; ?> 
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: It looks like your theme's page template has commented out `the_content()`...I would take a look at `page.php`, or any template partials (theme dependent)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything which could cause that comment (see edited post) :/
But I agree with your theory because if I copy {woocommerce_cart} shortcode to a random page, suddenly the cart appears well on that page...

Comment: Eeek, don't post that much code in the comments. Edit your question and properly format the code so people can actually read it.

Comment: And always try switching to a default theme (like Twenty Fifteen) to see if the issue persists. If it doesn't you have isolated the problem to your theme.

Comment: @helgatheviking Okay, I did switched to TwentyFiften, and everything works. That was a good idea, thank you. Where in my theme could the issue be? It's based on "Bones".

Comment: I restored the initial "page.php" code of my theme, with all the usual content, and turns out, it works again, I guess something must be essential on that page, now I have to clean up the code once again, but at least it works on my theme. Thank you for pointing me towards the good direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WooCommerce "My Account" and "Cart" pages should just be regular WordPress pages. The WooCommerce functionality is added by using shortcodes in the page content. You may also include other content and shortcodes if you would like, but the following shortcodes are required.

For the ***[Cart](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#cart)*** use:

```
[woocommerce_cart]
```

And for ***[My Account](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#my-account)*** use:

```
[woocommerce_my_account]
```

Your page template will need to make a call to `the_content()` so that the `$post->post_content` value is passed through the `the_content` filter which will call `do_shortcode()` to process the shortcodes.

```php
<?php get_header(); ?> 
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

<!-- output the page content here to process shortcodes -->
<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?> 
<?php else : ?>
 <?php endif; ?> 
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Your page isn't outputting any content. Add `<?php the_content(); ?>` inside the while loop and see if it works.

Comment: I believe that was the probleme yes! I didn't understood that cart/my account were basing themselves on "page.php" template and not "woocommerce.php"